# Method that returns either an integer either a string

Tags: java

I have to read options of menu from console and the options can be integer or string. my question is if there is another way to check of the input is string or int

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;


public class Read { 


    public Object read(){
        String option = null;
        BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        try {
            option = buffer.readLine();
            if(isInt(option)){
                return Integer.parseInt(option);
            } else if(isString(option)){
                return option;
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("IOException " +e.getMessage());
        }
        return null;
    }


    private boolean isString(String input){
        int choice = Integer.parseInt(input);
        if(choice >= 0){
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    private boolean isInt(String input){
        int choice = Integer.parseInt(input);
        if(choice >= 0){
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this?

```
boolean b = true:
try 
{ 
     int a = Integer.parseInt(input); 
} 
catch(NumberFormatException ex) 
{ 
      b = false;
}
```

If it's an not integer `b` will be false or else remains `true`

Comment: @Bohemian Yeah it  saves wrapping and unwrapping

Comment: Not just that - it means it can't be `null`; there are only two possible values of a boolean, but a Boolean has three.

Answer (score 1):

It depends what you mean by "integer".

If you mean "a whole number", the simplest and best way is use regex:

```
private boolean isInt(String input){
    return input.matches("\\d+");
}
```

If you mean "a java `int`", then you must attempt to parse it and treat an exception as proof it is not a valid `int`:

```
private boolean isInt(String input){
    try {
        Integer.parseInt(input);
        return true;
    } catch (NumberFormatException ignore) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use regex, then the method looks like this:

```
private boolean isInt(String input){
    return input.matches("\\d+");
}
```

Then the check it:

```
        if (isInt(option)){
            return Integer.parseInt(option);
        } else {
            return option;
        }
```